# ¿Que significa la tercera forma normal?

Tags: base-de-datos

La tercera forman normal dice que todas las columnas de la tabla deben de depender de la clave primaria, pero no se en que sentido deberían *"depender"*.

Estaba viendo esta tabla, me dijeron que estaba mal que el modelo estuviera ahí porque, el modelo aparte de depender del ID del vehículo también depende del fabricante.

```
    Modelo Fabricante VehiculoID
  --------------------------------
    AA1    Toyota     1
    AA2    Mitsubshi  2
```

¿Podría alguien explicarme eso?, por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagina la tabla

```
Id Modelo Marca  
+++++++++++++++++  
1  Cherokee Jeep  
2 Cherokee Jeep  
3 Ibiza Seat
```

"Marca" depende del modelo, no del coche concreto. Todos los Cherokee serán Jeep, independientemente del vehículo.

¿Qué puede pasar? Pues que tengas que hacer una corrección, y te quedes a medias, o que introduzcas/actualices valores inconsistentes

```
Id Modelo Marca  
+++++++++++++++++  
1  Cherokee Jeep  
2  Cherokee Seat  
3  Ibiza    Seat
```

Para normalizar, guardas solo el modelo, con una relación 1-N a los modelos, con marca siendo un atributo del modelo

```
Coche  
Id Modelo
++++++++++  
1  Cherokee  
2  Cherokee  
3  Ibiza   
 
Modelo  
Nombre Marca  
++++++++++++  
Cherokee Jeep  
Ibiza Seat
```

(por supuesto, igual quieres tener una id autogenerado en vez del nombre del modelo, pero eso es lo de menos).

Con este modelo, harás la consulta cruzando las dos tablas

```
SELECT Coche.Id, Coche.Modelo, Modelo.Marca FROM Coche, Marca WHERE Coche.Modelo = Modelo.Id
```

y nunca tendrás valores inconsistentes.

Answer (score 0):

Se podría explicar mejor con este ejemplo:

```
EstudianteID    Nombre  Edad    Nivel
          1     Juan    15      Segundo
          2     Lucas   14      Primero
          3     Maria   15      Segundo
```

Al depender el nivel de la clave primaria EstudianteID, obliga a generar redundancia repitiendo en este caso dos veces el nivel Segundo.
Para normalizar la base de datos se requiere crear otra tabla y referenciarla desde la tabla Estudiante.
**Nivel**

```
NivelID  Nombre
     1   Primero
     2   Segundo
```

**Estudainte**

```
EstudianteID    Nombre  Edad    NivelIDF
          1     Juan    15      1
          2     Lucas   14      2
          3     Maria   15      1
```

De esta forma solo se tendrá en la base de datos un registro para el nivel Primero y un registro para el nivel Segundo.
Similarmente en tu ejemplo, habría que crear las tablas adicionales Fabricante y Modelo para quedar en la 3ra forma normal.